# How to debug pro*cobol program which takes file name as argument

Tags: sql, unix, cobol, microfocus, procobol

How to debug **Microfocus cobol** programs that take arguments, like `rtsora Program-name ${filename.txt}`

Comment: What problem are you having that cannot be resolved by using DISPLAYs and documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the +A switch for example:

rtsora (+A) Program-name ${filename.txt}